# How to fetch the NATIVE resolution of attached monitor from EDID file through VB6.0?

Tags: vb6

I am developing a VB application in which i need to know the native resolution of the monitor and not the one set by the user(current resolution). So i need to read the EDID (extended display identification data) directly from the monitor.

I did try to find the resolution of monitor through some programs...but all it returns is the current resolution. Any help to read the info directly from EDID of monitor is appriciable.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some source code (although C/C++) to read the EDID block see Point 5 at [this link](http://thetweaker.wordpress.com/2011/11/13/reading-monitor-physical-dimensions-or-getting-the-edid-the-right-way/). The only official means to retrieve this information through [Windows Setup API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc185682%28VS.85%29.aspx).

For an EDID format description see for example [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_display_identification_data).

Answer (score 8):

After a lot of research i was able to fix my problem..
Thanks for the the valuable info Yahia.

First, we need to find the EDID data . The physical display information is in fact available to the OS, via Extended Display Identification Data(EDID). A copy of the EDID block is kept in the windows registry. But the problem was to obtain the correct EDID, as the registry has information stored about all the monitors which have been, at any point of time, attached to the system. So, first we use a WMI class “Win32_DesktopMonitor”, and through a simple SQL query grab the  PNP device id to find a monitor that is available (not offline). We can then dig into the registry to find the data.

`'for monitor in wmiquery('Select * from Win32_DesktopMonitor'):

regkey = ('HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\' +
                    monitor.PNPDeviceID + '\Device Parameters\EDID')
                edid = get_regval(regkey)'`

Second, it is necessary to parse the data. The base EDID information of a display is conveyed within a 128-byte data structure that contains pertinent manufacturer and operation-related data. Most of this information is uninteresting to us.

To know the NATIVE resolution we need to start looking in the DTD ( Detailed timing descriptor ) which starts at byte = 54.

Following is the logic for finding the maximum resolution from the EDID

`dtd = 54  # start byte of detailed timing desc.

horizontalRes = ((edid[dtd+4] >> 4) << 8) | edid[dtd+2]
verticalRes = ((edid[dtd+7] >> 4) << 8) | edid[dtd+5]
res=(horizontalRes,verticalRes)`

The values obtained are Hex values which can be converted to Decimal to find the NATIVE RESOLUTION in pixels.

Thanks
Hope it helps
Sachin

Comment: Hey, this helped me after looking for an answer for weeks, maybe even months.  I also want to know how to get the exact refresh rate from EDID, and the wikipedia page isn't really doing a good job of explaining that.  By any chance have you been able to do this?

Comment: @NmdMystery : I am glad that it helped. No, i have not looked into the  refresh rate from EDID.

Answer (score 2):

'Here is a complete solution for everything except for actually setting the resolution. This will read out the native resolution settings from the EDID of the active monitor.

Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002
Const DTD_INDEX = 54

strComputer = "."

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set oReg=GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\" & strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")

Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_DesktopMonitor",,48)
For Each objItem in colItems 'Gets active monitor EDID registry path
    strKeyPath = "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\" & objItem.PNPDeviceID & "\Device Parameters"
Next

oReg.GetBinaryValue HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,strKeyPath,"EDID",arrRawEDID

hor_resolution = arrRawEDID(DTD_INDEX + 2) + (arrRawEDID(DTD_INDEX + 4) And 240) * 16
vert_resolution = arrRawEDID(DTD_INDEX + 5) + (arrRawEDID(DTD_INDEX + 7) And 240) * 16

WshShell.Run "res.exe " & hor_resolution & " " & vert_resolution