# Get native resolution of screen

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, screen-resolution

Is there a way to get the native resolution of a screen in c#?

The reason that I ask is that I have some curves and it is very important that they look the same no matter what resolution. When the screen isn't in native resolution they look somewhat different than before and I want to show a warning that that is the case.

Comment: You need to take in to account the aspect ratio when you draw your curve.

Comment: Ok sorry, I'm using .NET with WPF.

Comment: I'm guessing that you are actually talking about the intrinsic resolution of an LCD panel.  The only really sane assumption to make is that the user selected a video adapter resolution that matches the LCD panel's resolution.  If he didn't then it will always look ugly, explicitly writing code to deal with a mistake isn't that useful.  If you really want to dig this out then you'll need to do something with WMI.

Comment: The users has in this case been known to occasionally have other resolutions than the native resolution. I need to create a warning that informs them that the curve might look a tiny bit different than it should because of their resolution. All the users aren't in this case the most computer savvy. I'll look into the WMI thing though.

Comment: How do you expect in inexperienced user to react to such a message?  He'll have absolutely no idea what you are talking about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From my experience the best solution is to extract that information from the monitors' [EDID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_display_identification_data)

How to get the native resolution is answered in: [How to fetch the NATIVE resolution of attached monitor from EDID file through VB6.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10073261/how-to-fetch-the-native-resolution-of-attached-monitor-from-edid-file-through-vb)

i have made a little javascript that gets the resolution out of the 8 bytes starting at 54.

```
var dtd = 0;
var edid =  new Uint8Array(8);
var i = 0;

edid[i++] = 0x0E;
edid[i++] = 0x1F;
edid[i++] = 0x00;
edid[i++] = 0x80;
edid[i++] = 0x51;
edid[i++] = 0x00;
edid[i++] = 0x1B;
edid[i++] = 0x30;

var horizontalRes = ((edid[dtd+4] >> 4) << 8) | edid[dtd+2] ;
var verticalRes = ((edid[dtd+7] >> 4) << 8) | edid[dtd+5];
console.log(horizontalRes+", "+verticalRes);
```

and here is a C# version:

```
    static Point ExtractResolution(byte [] edid)
    {
        const int dtd = 54;
        var horizontalRes = ((edid[dtd + 4] >> 4) << 8) | edid[dtd + 2];
        var verticalRes = ((edid[dtd + 7] >> 4) << 8) | edid[dtd + 5];
        return new Point(horizontalRes, verticalRes);
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Generally, Max Resolution is the Native Resolution for LCD Displays. However, that's not always the case. If we can leverage there, getting Max Resolutions should suffice.

Max Resolution can be obtained using:

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern int EnumDisplaySettings(string deviceName, int modeNum, ref DeviceMode devMode);

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the max resolution + refresh rate supported by specific display
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="deviceName">Device name(System.Windows.Forms.Screen.DeviceName)</param>
    /// <param name="dispWidth">Width of the display</param>
    /// <param name="dispHeight">Height of the display</param>
    /// <param name="refreshRate">Refresh rate of the display</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static void GetMaxResolutionWithRefreshRate(string deviceName, out int dispWidth, out int dispHeight, out int refreshRate)
    {
        dispWidth = dispHeight = refreshRate = 0;
        DeviceMode deviceMode = new DeviceMode();
        for (int i = 0; Win32.EnumDisplaySettings(deviceName, i, ref deviceMode) != 0; i++)
        {
            if (deviceMode.dmPelsWidth > dispWidth || (deviceMode.dmPelsWidth == dispWidth && deviceMode.dmPelsHeight >= dispHeight && deviceMode.dmDisplayFrequency >= refreshRate))
            {
                dispWidth = deviceMode.dmPelsWidth;
                dispHeight = deviceMode.dmPelsHeight;
                refreshRate = deviceMode.dmDisplayFrequency;
            }
        }
    }

public static void GetMaxResolutionWithRefreshRate(out int dispWidth, out int dispHeight, out int refreshRate)
    {
        GetMaxResolutionWithRefreshRate(null, out dispWidth, out dispHeight, out refreshRate);
    }
```

Comment: Not sure if it's robust enough for production but for my personal tools it's working well

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:-

```
GraphicsAdapter.DefaultAdapter.CurrentDisplayMode.Width
GraphicsAdapter.DefaultAdapter.CurrentDisplayMode.Height
```

To get the current resolution of the screen you can use:-

```
Rectangle resolution = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
```

Now for changing the resolution.

Check out this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6810/Dynamic-Screen-Resolution).

```
Screen screen = Screen.PrimaryScreen;
int S_width=screen.Bounds.Width;
int S_height=screen.Bounds.Height;
```

Comment: My Apple Macbook Retina has a native resolution of 2880x1800. I've chosen that in resolution settings. However since Windows scales it because it's high DPI `Screen class` tells me the resolution is 1440x900. The problem is that DWM also says the DPI is 96 which is fine in most cases, but if you need to know the native resolution `Screen` can't help you.