# How to get windows recommended resolution?

Tags: c#, .net

Is there any way I can get system recommended resolution in Windows 10?

I have looked for WMI or some .net API but still not found some useful information.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I always assumed the recommended resolution is just the native resolution of the screen, so see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18188825/get-native-resolution-of-screen

Comment: What do you plan to do with this information? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I want to get recommended resolution to compare with current resolution. If check current resolution is match recommended resolution or not.