# Is there a way to get the native resolution in c++ & winapi?

Tags: c++, winapi

Is there a way to get the recommended resolution in c++ & winapi?

I get only the current resolution by using `GetMonitorInfo`, `EnumDisplaySettings`, `EnumDisplayMonitors` or `GetSystemMetrics`.

**Edit:** 
After some research i found this example code [Example code for displaying an app on a portrait device](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/display/displaying-app-on-portrait-device).

Even if it is not about the native resolution it shows how to get it. For that have a look at the functions `HRESULT GetPathInfo(_In_ PCWSTR pszDeviceName, _Out_ DISPLAYCONFIG_PATH_INFO* pPathInfo)` and `bool IsNativeOrientationPortrait(const LUID AdapterLuid, const UINT32 TargetId)`.

The code works so far but I do not know how it behaves under windows 8.1 and previous versions. Have not made any further tests.

Comment: I recommend visit https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a265592a-63b7-44ab-91af-6f934378e6bc/how-to-get-the-recommend-resolution-native-resolution?forum=vcgeneral

Comment: The recommended resolution is the monitor's native resolution.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/10073368/17034

Comment: If someone has intentionally set their monitor to a non-native resolution, isn't that the resolution that they want to use?  Why pixel-shame them?  ;-)

Comment: @dave This isn't about shaming. It's about finding the native resolution of the monitor.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan the question asks about "preferred" and "recommended" resolution though, not the native resolution.  Perhaps it's a translation error and Zen1000 meant to say "native" but if so it would be good to edit the question title and text to make that  more clear.

Comment: @DaveS the question also specifies that he's not interested in the current resolution, even enumerating the many methods that we can obtain it. Other than the current resolution and the native resolution of the monitor, I don't see what other resolution the question could possibly be asking about.

Comment: @DaveS Yes, i meant the native resolution, although i didnt know that it was different that the preferred/recommended resolution. I changed the title

Comment: @BattleTested thanks to your hint i found out the example and managed to get the native resolution

Comment: @Dave The term "preferred" is the term used by the Windows GUI in the display settings dialog

Answer (score 3):

Actually, you can do a GetSupportedFullScreenResolutions to get the list of resolutions the monitor support and usually the last index is the best(highest) resolution for the monitor.

Like this:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    DEVMODE dm = { 0 };
    dm.dmSize = sizeof(dm);
    for (int iModeNum = 0; EnumDisplaySettings(NULL, iModeNum, &dm) != 0; iModeNum++) 
    {
        cout << "Mode #" << iModeNum << " = " << dm.dmPelsWidth << "x" << dm.dmPelsHeight << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT:

You can get the resolution of the graphics card and compare the maximum resolution obtained with the screen resolution. In general, the smallest of the two is the best resolution.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    UINT32 PathArraySize = 0;
    UINT32 ModeArraySize = 0;
    DISPLAYCONFIG_PATH_INFO* PathArray;
    DISPLAYCONFIG_MODE_INFO* ModeArray;
    DISPLAYCONFIG_TOPOLOGY_ID CurrentTopology;
    //Directly query the resolution of the graphics card and get the physical resolution all the time.
    GetDisplayConfigBufferSizes(QDC_ALL_PATHS, &PathArraySize, &ModeArraySize);
    PathArray = (DISPLAYCONFIG_PATH_INFO*)malloc(PathArraySize * sizeof(DISPLAYCONFIG_PATH_INFO));
    memset(PathArray, 0, PathArraySize * sizeof(DISPLAYCONFIG_PATH_INFO));
    ModeArray = (DISPLAYCONFIG_MODE_INFO*)malloc(ModeArraySize * sizeof(DISPLAYCONFIG_MODE_INFO));
    memset(ModeArray, 0, ModeArraySize * sizeof(DISPLAYCONFIG_MODE_INFO));
    LONG ret = QueryDisplayConfig(QDC_DATABASE_CURRENT, &PathArraySize, PathArray, &ModeArraySize, ModeArray, &CurrentTopology);

    int x_DisplayConfigScreen = ModeArray->targetMode.targetVideoSignalInfo.activeSize.cx;
    int y_DisplayConfigScreen = ModeArray->targetMode.targetVideoSignalInfo.activeSize.cy;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does not work if the monitor supports higher resolutions than the native.

Comment: @Zen1000 Then you can get the maximum resolution supported by graphics cards and compare it with the screen resolution. Usually the smallest of the two is the best resolution.